# is there a way to find total sum of children with the same child name using firebase in a flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, storage

I'm having a hard time calculating the sum of a specific set of children with the same name. I did it like this, but it does not work. Please help.

```
driverRef.orderByChild("earnings")
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
          print("PPPP" + dataSnapShot.value.toString());
          if (dataSnapShot.value != null) {
            print("kkkk" + j.values.toList()[i]["fare"].toString());

           sum = double.parse(j.values.toList()[i]["fare"].toString())+sum;
            print("JJJJJ" + sum.toString());
            // double oldEarnings = double.parse(
            //     j.values.toList()[i]["fare"].toString());
            // double oldEarnings=sum;
            double totalEarnings = fareAmount + sum;

            driverRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid)
                .child("earnings")
                .set(
                totalEarnings.toStringAsFixed(2));
          } else {
            double totalEarnings = fareAmount.toDouble();
            driverRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid).child("earnings").set(
                totalEarnings.toStringAsFixed(2));
          }
```

Comment: Hi There .What are `i` and `j` here. You need to post your data samples and explain what you are try to retrive from them.

Comment: Can you share some info on your database structure. Maybe a automated counter from the firebase cloud functions would be a better solution for you. It would save you a lot of reads because you could just get the finished cound and won't need to get the whole list of elements and read them localy.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9uDs.png)Finish reference has fare, i want to find total fare of all fare children

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQpjd.png)

`

void saveEarnings(int fareAmount)
{
FinishRequestRef.orderByChild("Driver Details").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){

```
  if(snapshot.value!=null){
    Map<dynamic,dynamic>j=snapshot.value;
    for (var i = 0; i <j.length; i++)
      if (j.values.toList()[i]["Driver Details"]["drivers_id"] ==
          currentFirebaseUser.uid) {
        // driverRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid).child("earnings")
        //     .once()
        //     .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
        //             print("PPPP"+dataSnapShot.value.toString());
        //   if (dataSnapShot.value == null) {
        //     print("pppp");
        //
        //     double totalEarnings = fareAmount.toDouble();
        //     driverRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid).child("earnings").set(
        //         totalEarnings.toStringAsFixed(2));}
        // });
        driverRef.orderByChild("earnings")
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
          print("PPPP" + dataSnapShot.value.toString());
          if (dataSnapShot.value != null) {
            print("kkkk" + j.values.toList()[i]["fare"].toString());
            //var dos= dataSnapShot.value.toString();
            double sum=0.0;
           sum += double.parse(j.values.toList()[i]["fare"].toString());
            print("JJJJJ" + sum.toString());
            // double oldEarnings = double.parse(
            //     j.values.toList()[i]["fare"].toString());
            // double oldEarnings=sum;
            double totalEarnings = fareAmount + sum;

            driverRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid)
                .child("earnings")
                .set(
                totalEarnings.toStringAsFixed(2));
          } else {
            double totalEarnings = fareAmount.toDouble();
            driverRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid).child("earnings").set(
                totalEarnings.toStringAsFixed(2));
          }
        });
      }
     }});}`[enter image description here][1] All the finish references fare amounts must be added to drivers earnings child added with cur
```